# How to set images in adobe acrobat checkbox

Tags: pdf, acrobat, pdf-form

I have Acrobat XI.  I am trying to convert an old pdf to a new pdf form.  I have a series of boxes that are to be used to declare a status of something.

The values in the handwritten form are blank, check, plus sign, and minus sign.  How do I simulate that using form elements?
THanks

Answer (score 0):

Do the boxes need to be active (meaning clickable)?

Instead of checkboxes with their very limited number of symbols available, you would use Buttons, with an according symbol as icon. Then you are adding a little bit of simple logic to show/hide the buttons, or, if you want to be fancy, you may also change the icons using buttonGetIcon() and buttonSetIcon().